# Laravel setter injection

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

How can i use setter dependency injection with Laravel's service container to have automatic dependency resolution?

Here's an example:

```
class Test
{
    (...)

    public function setMailer(Mailer $mailer) 
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    (...)

    function sendEmail()
    {
        $this->mailer->send(new Email('john.doe@example.com'));
    }
}
```

How can i ensure that, when `sendEmail()` is called, the mailer dependency is statisfied? How can i leverage Laravel's service container to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/dependency-injection-laravels-ioc/ have a look at this.

Comment: I'm looking for answers to the same question...

Answer (score 3):

There is no way for you to ensure that other method is ran before `sendEmail` is ran and the only method that could have 'method injection' would be `setMailer`.

If you wanted method injection for the `setMailer` method you would have to use the IoC container to call that method:

```
$a = new Test;
app()->call([$a, 'setMailer']);
```

This will have the container call `setMailer` on `$a` for you and will resolve any dependencies needed, in this case.

Having the container call `sendEmail` would be exactly the same as calling it yourself, as there are no arguments.

If you really wanted a mailer to be available, you could use constructor injection so you have the mailer before `sendEmail` is called.

```
public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}
```